# Bootstrap nav bar suddenly broken

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

[image]I've managed to somehow break my bootstrap nav bar while trying to fix another element of my site.

I cannot figure out what I did to change the nav? It's supposed to be all in one line, the text elements floated left and the social icons floated right. (image of what it is supposed to look like is at the top)

When the menu collapses into an icon, the menu items are supposed to all be aligned to the right.

Can anyone help me figure out what the heck is going on!?!

http://brucennial.com/v3main.html

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the built-in `.navbar-left` and `.navbar-right` classes on your `.navbar-nav`'s. Don't create your own...

Also, remove any custom classes on the child `li`'s, you shouldnt need any...

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/45j5T/3/)

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    //Colored links
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    //social icons
</ul>
```

Align links to right on mobile view....

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
    .navbar-nav li{
        text-align: right;    
    }
}
```

Instead of using `hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg`, you can just use `.visible-xs`.

Remove `hidden-xs` from your "social icon" `li`s and add it to the parent `navbar-nav`.

If you are going to use Bootstrap, don't edit the bootstrap CSS directly, just override the styles in your own stylesheet. You can use the [Customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

add `text-align: right;` to `.container > .navbar-header, .container > .navbar-collapse` in /css/v3_bootstrap.css:4440

and `text-align: left;` to same slectors `.container > .navbar-header, .container > .navbar-collapse` but on line 4448 (afer `@media (min-width: 768px)`)

The example above is moving all menu items to the right side, but if you need to display them in one line

1. set `display: inline` for `.nav > li` on line 4096 and `.nav > li > a` on 4101
2. add put `.nav > li a, .nav > li > a` with `display: block;` inside `@media (min-width: 768px)` section

Comment: hmm i've tried this but it's not working. i attached image of what i'm trying to accomplish in the post

Comment: @Waverly, I didn't get it for the first time, check out my edition